# Res.render and res.json re-reading from database

Tags: json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a route

```
app.get('/info', function(req, res){
    Information.findById(..., function(err,information){
        res.render('info-page', {information: information}
    });
})
```

However, I want to be able to use `information` on the client-side, so rendering the page with `information` will not let me do that. The other way is to then have

```
app.get('/api/info', function(req, res){
    Information.findById(..., function(err,information){
        res.json(information}
    });
})
```

which will be called by an angular controller. However, this seems inefficient because I would be adding Angular to my application solely to do this and it requires me reading twice from the database. What can I do to both render information, use it on my client-side, and avoid reading twice from the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Pug (old Jade):

```
script.
  information="#{information}";
```

in your template "info-page"